# Oracle: How to return rows based on a value that is held by a cell of a row and not a column?

Tags: sql

Not sure if I'm really asking the right question here, and I don't even know where to begin so I don't have much code.

Anyways, the question is: Display the last name, first name, and pack_id for all customers who have the same pack_id as the customers named 'Amado Taylor'

There is a table called customers where there is a first_name, last_name, and a pack_ID.

I asked my teacher about it and he said to use a self join, and I understand that function, but I don't still how to make the query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: remove irrelevant database tag. It should be wither Oracle or MySQL. Anyways the query for your use wont change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Query with self join

```
select * from customers c
inner join
customers c1
on c.pack_id=c1.pack_id
and c1.first_name = 'Amado' and 
c1.last_name - 'Taylor'
```

But you can also use this

```
select * From customers where pack_Id in
(
select pack_id from customers
where first_name = 'Amado' and last_name = 'Taylor'
)
```

You can also use inner query as a separate table and use this to join `customers` on `pack_id`

Comment: This doesn't look like a self-join, which is what the instructor said to use.

Comment: As 'IN' would be faster than join, hence I mentioned that in comments. Anyways I gave the query with `join` as well.

Comment: Thanks dude, that answered my question. Would there be any difference if you were to switch c1.first_name with c.first_name or is it just arbitrary information due to the nature of a self join?

Comment: In your case, you can switch. Both will work. 
If the answer worked for you, then please accept it so the question could be closed. Thanks!

Comment: An IN is most likely faster, but giving an answer different than what was asked for isn't correct. It's like someone asking where to find the nearest Best Buy to get parts to repair their PC and telling them to go to the nearest Apple Genius Bar and ask directions to Best Buy. The Geniuses may know, but it would be more correct to just give them the Best Buy location they asked for in the first place directly.